# how to backup the sqlite db into sdcard in phonegap android?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm doing android application using phonegap(HTML5, JavaScript).
I need to backup the sqlite database to the SD card.
I created a plugin to backup the database but it's not worked.

how to backup the sqlite database into sdcard in phonegap android using javascript code?